# When does this LINQ query go to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, ado.net

I'm concerned that this LINQ call actually makes two trips to the database (once for Contains, once for ToList), when all I really want is the SQL-equivalent of a nested select statement:

```
var query1 = from y in e.cities where y.zip=12345 select y.Id;
var query2 = from x in e.users where query1.Contains(x.cityId) select x;
List<users> result = query2.ToList();
```

The point: If this is making a trip to the database twice, how do I avoid that?  How can I have a nested select statement like this that will just execute as one query one time?  Query1 will only ever return 1 or 0 rows.  There must be a better way than using "Contains".

Comment: Easy way to find out: watch the connection. If that is LINQ-to-SQL, hook `ctx.Log = ...`, or SQL profiler works, or mvc-mini-profiler, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `query1` and `query2` are both `IQueryable` there is only one trip to the database - when you call `query2.ToList()`

You could combine the queries using a join since you are looking for related information and the relationship is that the user's city id is the same as the city you are restricting to:

```
var result = (from x in e.users 
                join y in e.cities
                on x.cityId equals y.Id
                where y.zip == 12345
                select x.Id).ToList();
```

Above should give you a list of user ids of users that (presumably) live in the zip code 12345.

Comment: Sorry, changed that.  So you're saying "Contains" does not actually make a trip to the database?  Wouldn't it need to in order to define query2?

Comment: You're calling me out on all my typos!  Once again, sorry.  Id => cityId

Comment: @CarlBenson: Fixed in my answer

Comment: I suppose technically, you can always use Joins instead of nested Select statements that only return one row.  Any reason not to?

Comment: @CarlBenson: Could be that you use the same sub-query in multiple other queries so you could factor it out to keep your code base smaller, in most other cases I can think of I would prefer a join - it is just more readable. In your particular case it also should be more performant (not 100% sure though as Linq already optimizes so it depends on the generated SQL). Also it doesn't matter whether the cities part returns zero, one or multiple rows.